# The inline position of small pictures of equations in a text is too high

Tags: kindle

I am writing a technical Ebook for the Kindle of Amazon. My text is in a Word doc and has a lot of formulas.
The main formulas are each written on an own line in the text with a formula number at the end.
Depending on the structure of the formula they can have larger height than one line.
Normally the height average level where the = sign is on is equal to the line level.
When i make the Kindle file i found out that first I have to transfer all equations into pictures. I found out that this can be done by CRTL+SHIFT+F9 .

The result in the Kindle previewer is that all main formulas are OK, but the small formulas in between the text,such as q=A/b, are not properly placed relative to the line level.
They appear as a picture on top of the base of the line which results in a far to high position of the = sign.

Is there a solution for this problem?